# Anyone knows about Android 4.1+ offline voice-recognition API documentation?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I'm trying to build an offline voice recognition Android app on Android 4.1.2 and 4.3, and I'm trying to get access to Android ASR API. I could find all information related to synchronous voice recognition (using an intent) on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html, but nothing about asynchronous recognition (I would like to recognize the audio content from a file).

Does anyone know about an API documentation and tutorials on this topic?

Many thanks!

Edit : Many thanks Kaarel for your answer. If I put what I'm trying to do in another way : I have an audio file where I have recorded a speech, and I would like to send the content of this file to the Android recognizer in offline mode (e.g. without internet connection). The issue is that I have been able to use Android speech recognition while the user is speaking (what I call 'synchronous'), but not using a file (e.g. after the user is done speaking, what I call asynchronous).

Comment: Explain what you mean by asynchronous and synchronous, and what does it have to do with offline and recognizing audio content from a file.

Answer (score 2):

Android's speech API (as of version 4.3) does not offer speech recognition of a pre-recorded audio. Also, the API does not allow the client to declare that speech recognition should happen offline.